# How to get value from select items in ListView multi-column in android

Tags: java, android, listview, parameter-passing

I wish to know How to get values from selected items in a multi-column ListView  in android?
and show value in a new activity.

Comment: add some code...and first read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

in order to get selected item you should use appropriate event listener for example if you and to get item you clicked use this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
        + id);
  }
});
```

if you need to pass something from one activity to other you can do it via intent

```
 intent.putExtra("KEY", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KEY");
```

note in order to pass an object to other activity it must be serializable 
regarding ot list item click listener there also might be problems with getting item focus